# ssh login fails for user with empty password

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, pam

How do you enable ssh login on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) for a user with an empty password? I've seen others asking this question, and like me it's for the same reason: a parent who can't deal with passwords. So "set a password" is not an option.

I found references to adding "nullok" to various PAM config files. Didn't work.
Found sshd config "PermitEmptyPasswords yes". Didn't work.

**Updated info:** A public/private ssh key pair is set up, and is being used successfully on my account (which has a password) on the same machine. File permissions for the ~/.ssh directory and private key are correct.

I've done a diff on "ssh -vvv" between a successful ssh with a password-enabled account and the one with no password.

```
54,55c54,55
< debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256
< debug2: bits set: 533/1024
---
> debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 140/256
> debug2: bits set: 508/1024
67c67
< debug2: bits set: 509/1024
---
> debug2: bits set: 516/1024
79c79
< debug2: key: /Users/rae/.ssh/rae (0x7f9a0241e2c0)
---
> debug2: key: /Users/rae/.ssh/rae (0x7f81e0c1e2c0)
90,116c90,224
< debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
< debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
< debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
< debug3: remaining preferred: password
< debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
< debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
< debug2: userauth_kbdint
< debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
< debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 14 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)
< debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
< debug2: userauth_kbdint
< debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
< debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 14 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)
< debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
< debug2: userauth_kbdint
< debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req
< debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
< debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 14 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)
< debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
< debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
< debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
< Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
---
> debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
> debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 6e:02:20:63:48:6a:08:99:b8:5f:12:d8:d5:3d:e1:fb
> debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: DSA 6e:02:20:63:48:6a:08:99:b8:5f:12:d8:d5:3d:e1:fb
> debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
> Authenticated to cme-mini.local ([192.168.1.5]:22).
> debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
> debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
> debug2: channel 0: send open
> debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
> debug1: Entering interactive session.
> debug2: callback start
> debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
> debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
> debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
> debug1: Sending environment.
```

Comment: try using authentication keys for ssh.

Comment: "a parent who can't deal with passwords." -> Welcome but this website is not for home related question : http://serverfault.com/faq .

Comment: ssh keys are in place. Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm really trying to log in using an already set up private/public ssh key pair. These keys are valid and are being used for my account on the same machine. File permissions for the private key file are correct (read by user only, write by user only).  
  
As to "home related", I don't think configuring sshd to handle various password arrangements is a very typical "home" question.

Comment: @Reid Typical or not, home questions are **explicitly** off topic per the [FAQ].  This is a fundamentally good question though - if you post the full `ssh -vvv` output from the unsuccessful login I'll move it over to [unix.se] for you and take a look to see if I can figure out what's wrong -- reading a diff is screwing up all the context). (@ me in a comment once you've updated the question so I get notified -- if I don't spot the problem I'm sure someone on U&L will.)

Comment: @Reid (you may also want to look at the sshd logs. I think they're in in `/var/log/secure.log` on OS X, and that might tell you what the server doesn't like)

Comment: For future generations, the problem is that Mac OS X adds a line to /etc/sshd_config of the form: "`DenyUsers <mainUser>`", I assume as part of the initialization of the machine at OS install time, so just comment that line out and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing remote logins without password is asking for problems. Since you indicated that educating the user is not an option you are left with generating an ssh key. Those can be used without password, or with a passphrase (which is easier to remember).

According to the guide at [this site](http://drupal.org/node/1070130) that is easy to do.

Comment: There is a valid ssh key in ~/.ssh and still login is not possible.